# Prevent tabular from jumping to next page

Tags: tables, page-breaking

I am trying to get this tabular into a page that already has text in it. The table jumps to the next page and the text that was supposed to be on the next page, jumps up on the page where the table should be.

- What should I do?

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Regression results }
\begin{tabular}{llll}
    \hline
    \textbf{FDI} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}OLS\\ (1)\end{tabular}    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}FE\\ (2)\end{tabular}             & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}FGLS\\ (3)\end{tabular}          \\ \hline
    FDI.L1    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.65*\\ (0.02)\end{tabular}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.93**\\ (0.4)\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.72*\\ (0.00)\end{tabular}  \\
    INFR      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.42***\\ (0.13)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.4072***\\ (0.1504)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.45*\\ (0.0)\end{tabular}  \\
    EXCH      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.40***\\ (0.17)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.49***\\ (0.15)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.45*\\ (0.36)\end{tabular}  \\
    MRKTS     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1.51\\ (0.73)\end{tabular}    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1.1\\ (0.7)\end{tabular}    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1.1*\\ (0.08)\end{tabular}  \\
    MRKTS.L1  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.85***\\ (0.26)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.55***\\ (0.24)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.7477*\\ (0.2261)\end{tabular}  \\
    UNMP      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}-0.0236\\ (0.09)\end{tabular}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}-0.06\\ (0.07)\end{tabular}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}-0.04\\ (0.00)\end{tabular}  \\
    NEWS      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.56***\\ (0.25)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.56***\\ (0.29)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.58*\\ (0.28)\end{tabular}  \\
    NEGT      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.23***\\ (0.02)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.23***\\ (0.7)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.31**\\ (0.17)\end{tabular} \\
    CANDC     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.02\\ (0.08)\end{tabular}    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.02\\ (0.00)\end{tabular}    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.01\\ (0.17)\end{tabular}   \\
    Country 2 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}-0.10\\ (0.13)\end{tabular}   & -                                                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}-0.24\\ (0.17)\end{tabular}  \\
    Country 3 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0.07\\ (0.33)\end{tabular}    & -                                                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}-0.18\\ (0.26)\end{tabular}  \\
    Country 4 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1.60***\\ (0.69)\end{tabular} & -                                                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1.56**\\ (0.67)\end{tabular} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Is on the page enough space for your table? You should provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` By the way, your table is rather strange composed (off-topic).

Comment: there is not enough space left on the page for the table.  you can increase the length of the page with `\enlargethispage`, but you could also move the input for the table up to the previous paragraph break, and give a "bottom" table option: `\begin{table}[b]`.  answers to this question provide a lot of information about table positioning.

Comment: Note that the _only_ reason to put anything in a `table` environment is to tell latex that the content can be moved to another page to help with page breaking.  a `tabular` on its own is never moved.

Comment: Have you tried changing `\begin{table}[]` to `\begin{table}[h!]`? (If there's not enough space left on the current page, the `[h!]` placement directive will evaluate to "top of the next page".)

Comment: The `table` environment is just to do this. Your options are: (a) Do not use `table`. (b) Use the option `[h]`  (c) Use the option `[H]` that need the package `float` (d) reduce the table size o increase the text area, so it can be fitted in the first page, and (e) maybe remove previous floats .... or (f)  left the table without options, use a `\caption{}` and use the cross-references with `\label{xxx}` and  `\ref{xxx}` (this is indeed the best for maintain a good layout).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than spend any time on trying to position the table on the current page, I'd make more of an effort to make the table more readable -- and visually appealing to your readers. For instance, load the `dcolumn` package and align all numbers on their respective decimal markers. While you're at it, do take the opportunity to simplify the code *drastically*, say along the lines shown in the following example, which contains just 1 `tabular` environment rather than 40 [!!].

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!] % place table on current page, if at all possible
\centering
\caption{Regression results}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\scshape}l *{3}{d{2.5}} @{}}
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
    FDI    & \mc{OLS} & \mc{FE}  & \mc{FGLS} \\
           & \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)} \\ 
    \midrule
    fdi.l1 &  0.65^{*}   &  0.93^{**}  &  0.72^{*} \\
           & (0.02)   & (0.4)    & (0.00) \\
    infr   &  0.42^{***} & 0.4072^{***}&  0.45^{*} \\ 
           & (0.13)   & (0.1504) & (0.0)  \\
    exch   &  0.40^{***} &  0.49^{***} &  0.45^{*} \\
           & (0.17)   & (0.15)   & (0.36) \\
    mrkts  &  1.51    &  1.1     &  1.1^{*}  \\
           & (0.73)   & (0.7)    & (0.08) \\
    mrkts.l1& 0.85^{***} &  0.55^{***} &  0.7477^{*} \\
           & (0.26)   & (0.24)   & (0.2261) \\
    unmp   & -0.0236  & -0.06    & -0.04  \\ 
           & (0.09)   & (0.07)   & (0.00) \\
    news   &  0.56^{***} &  0.56^{***} &  0.58^{*} \\
           & (0.25)   & (0.29)   & (0.28) \\
    negt   &  0.23^{***} &  0.23^{***} &  0.31^{**} \\
           & (0.02)   & (0.7)    & (0.17) \\
    candc  &  0.02    &  0.02    &  0.01  \\
           & (0.08)   & (0.00)   & (0.17) \\
    country 2 &-0.10  & \mc{--}  & -0.24  \\
           & (0.13)   &          & (0.17) \\
    country 3 & 0.07  & \mc{--}  & -0.18  \\
           & (0.33)   &          & (0.26) \\
    country 4 & 1.60^{***} & \mc{--}& 1.56^{**} \\
           & (0.69)   &          & (0.67) \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't like the “(standard errors in parentheses)” part alone in the middle of the environment; it's just by chance that it's aligned with the (short) caption: if the caption is longer, the alignment would be wrong. Either it goes in the caption or at the bottom of the table as a legend, together with the explanation of what the asterisks mean.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I quite agree - and, in consequence, I've deleted the string entirely. It'll be up to the OP to provide a suitable legend.

Answer (score 2):

What about `longtable`? it will start where you like to have table, but its end will be on the next page, for example like this:

[image]

MWE below is based on *Mico* nice polish of your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, dcolumn, longtable}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{longtable}{@{} >{\scshape}l *{3}{d{2.5}} @{}}
\caption{Regression results\newline}                           \\
\endfirsthead
\caption{Regression results (cont.)}     \\
    \toprule
\endhead
\midrule[0.6pt]
\multicolumn{4}{>{\footnotesize}r}{continue on the next page}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
    \toprule
    FDI    & \mc{OLS} & \mc{FE}  & \mc{FGLS}            \\
           & \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)} & \mc{(3)}             \\
    \midrule
    fdi.l1 &  0.65^{*}   &  0.93^{**}  &  0.72^{*}      \\
           & (0.02)   & (0.4)    & (0.00)               \\
    infr   &  0.42^{***} & 0.4072^{***}&  0.45^{*}      \\
           & (0.13)   & (0.1504) & (0.0)                \\
    exch   &  0.40^{***} &  0.49^{***} &  0.45^{*}      \\
           & (0.17)   & (0.15)   & (0.36)               \\
    mrkts  &  1.51    &  1.1     &  1.1^{*}             \\
           & (0.73)   & (0.7)    & (0.08)               \\
    mrkts.l1& 0.85^{***} &  0.55^{***} &  0.7477^{*}    \\
           & (0.26)   & (0.24)   & (0.2261)             \\
    unmp   & -0.0236  & -0.06    & -0.04                \\
           & (0.09)   & (0.07)   & (0.00)               \\
    news   &  0.56^{***} &  0.56^{***} &  0.58^{*}      \\
           & (0.25)   & (0.29)   & (0.28)               \\
    negt   &  0.23^{***} &  0.23^{***} &  0.31^{**}     \\
           & (0.02)   & (0.7)    & (0.17)               \\
    candc  &  0.02    &  0.02    &  0.01                \\
           & (0.08)   & (0.00)   & (0.17)               \\
    country 2 &-0.10  & \mc{--}  & -0.24                \\
           & (0.13)   &          & (0.17)               \\
    country 3 & 0.07  & \mc{--}  & -0.18                \\
           & (0.33)   &          & (0.26)               \\
    country 4 & 1.60^{***} & \mc{--}& 1.56^{**}         \\
           & (0.69)   &          & (0.67) \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```